# Getting the "like" button to appear on ALL of my web site's pages

Tags: web, facebook-like

I have been able to ge the "like" button to appear on my home page, but cannot get it to show up on ALL my pages on the site. I have tried copying & pasting this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:px"></iframe>
```

I found this code here:
http://www.greenlabeldesign.com.au/2010/04/inserting-the-facebook-like-feature-on-your-website/

Any suggestions on how to implement this feature? 
My web site is www.connieskids.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to include facebooks javascript file on all pages:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```